# Plug Apple Studio Display (USB-C/Thunderbolt) into an old-ish PC (HDMI, USB-A)?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

I recently got an Apple Studio Display as a second monitor for my 2020 iMac (M1). I do the majority of my work on a Mac and the Apple Studio Display is fantastic.

I'm a game developer though so I occasionally need to use a Windows PC for various things. Previously I had an old HDMI monitor that I used, and I could switch back and forth between plugging it into my Mac as a second monitor, and using it as the main screen for the PC.

Now I've upgraded the second monitor to an Apple Studio Display, do I have any options to plug it into the PC for occasional use? Unfortunately it's around 6 years old and wasn't particularly high end when I bought it, so only has USB-A and HDMI ports.

Would there be a dongle I could get? Or would I have to install a new (PCI?) card?

**Update:** The PC also has Display Port and DVI. So (Display Port or DVI) -> USB-C monitor could also be an option, if that's a thing.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can connect it with these two dongles: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08TWJ5HD8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08TWJ5HD8) (HDMI TO DISPLAY-PORT since the studio display is expecting to have a DisplayPort signal)
and

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B083YWGPW1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083YWGPW1) this one is a bidirectional Displayport to thunderbolt 3 cable. that was the only thing that worked for me to connect my steam deck and a ps4 to my Studio display.